# Is Explain Plan in DB2 is Data Driven?

Tags: db2, sql-execution-plan

In DB2 data studio while extracting a Explain plan please confirm if it depends on table's data. 
Let's say, I have one table with 500 records in testing environment and the same table has 50000 records in production database. So if I extract the explain plan that is using same table then will it give me same cost or different cost of query.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 4):

The calculated query cost depends on many things, including table statistics, possibly updated in real-time, database configuration parameters, and hardware characteristics. This means that the plan costs, as well as plans themeselves, are unlikely to be the same in different environments.

EDIT: Statistics about data, such as the number of rows in a table, the number of distinct values in a column etc. are updated by a special utility, `RUNSTATS`, and you need to ensure that it runs regularly to reflect changes to the data. If statistics are not updated (or never collected) the optimizer will know nothing about the data metrics and will be forced to make guesses, often resulting in suboptimal performance. In some cases when the optimizer discovers that the estimated statistics differ from the actual results of a query, it can trigger automatic statistics update.

Comment: so is table data is also one of the criteria for explain plan?

Comment: [RUNSTATS] is used to update the data for indexes but will it affect the Cost of a query shown in Explain plan.